# How transfer core data from iOS to watch

Tags: ios, core-data, synchronization

I have an iOS project that uses core data to store data. I need to do a watch application. How can I sync the core data from IOS to WatchOS?

Both the watch app and iOS app would insert a new record, and edit or delete a record.
If I use two datastore to store the record, I need to sync the difference between this two devices. Should I use `NSDictionary` to send or get data? If I do it this way, when I edit one record in two device, I need to pair which one is the newest, then save it.

Am I in the right way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you can have a Core Data model in the Watch Extension itself.

But for me, I would go about it by having the model only on the main app. Having one model means you don't have issues syncing data and ensuring they are both up to speed, also you don't double the memory of your core data model by having two. Seems redundant. In this case, when I need to save something from the phone, I would save it directly into the model from the phone. When I need to save something from the watch, I would send it to the phone and save it there.

If your Watch Extension needs an item from the Core Data, you could send a message to the phone, have the phone retrieve the data, and send it back in the reply handler.

Have a look at the apple documentation on how to send and receive data between the Watch and the Phone, it is based on using Dictionaries as you said: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession